# install.packages() is executed with no error, but library() cannot find/get the called package. Why?

Tags: r, install.packages

If `install.packages` is executed with no error, then why `library(...)` cannot find/get the called package?

```
install.packages("D:/R/PAKETLER/circumplex-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
library(`circumplex-master`)
# Error in library(`circumplex-master`) : there is no package called ‘circumplex-master’
library("circumplex-master")
# Error in library("circumplex-master") : there is no package called ‘circumplex-master’
library("circumplex")
# Error in library("circumplex") : there is no package called ‘circumplex’
library(circumplex)
# Error in library(circumplex) : there is no package called ‘circumplex’
```

Comment: Why aren't you installing from CRAN or GitHub?(Assuming this is the package you need: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circumplex/index.html)

Comment: `install.packages("circumplex") # Warning in install.packages : package ‘circumplex’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)`. I think, my R version is not accepted. I took zip file from CRAN. Though I thought first a tricky operation that is the changing R version in  `DESCRIPTION` such that it obeys my R version and then zipping it, and call it afterwards via `install.packages`. But, `install.packages("D:/R/PAKETLER/circumplex-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")` executed in my RStudio console with no error, no warning. Hence, I didnot make any such tricky modification.

Comment: Just update `R` unless there's a reason you don't want to or download earlier versions of the package.

Comment: @NelsonGon Microsoft R Open 3.4.3 is new RevoREnt. Also, Microsoft R Open 3.4.3 is compatible with R 3.4.3. Hence, if I load R 3.5.0, I cannot use MS R Open and Microsoft Machine Learning Server 9.3.0.